# Custom input for project job optimizer

Tags: optimization, input, optaplanner

I have been trying to make custom input for my project job scheduling, but the provided un solved examples are not understandable. Have to tried to make sense of it but there are lots of attribute which are not making sense.
Have tried the Optaplanner documentation but there is nothing documented on the structure of input we need to provide to the optaplanner.
I need to provide my custom data as an input for job scheduling.
Can some one guide me in the right direction.

Thanks

I have tried to understand the sample JSON input but as it is not documented so didn't understand the most of it

Comment: I am working at VRP.
Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The problem and the data format is described in [this paper](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/retrieve/289142/).
MISTA 2013 was a competition many years ago and this example was OptaPlanner's submission to that competition.

It doesn't serve as a good example of how to model project job scheduling because, as you already pointed out yourself, it is very generic and not very easy to understand.